# How to create desktop icon that runs jar command

Tags: jar

New to Linux but very happy with it so far and been able to learn a lot.

Currently opening a folder that contains Example.jar, then opening terminal, next entering  java -jar Example.jar to launch the jar file.

Ideally would like to double click a icon on the desktop to do the aforementioned.

Is this possible?

Running Linux Mint but believe the steps would be the same.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to create a `.desktop` file. To do this, create a new file named something like `ExampleLauncher.desktop` (the name isn't too important, since window managers will likely read the name from inside the file and display that inside). Then, open that file in your favorite editor (double-clicking may not work in this case, so you'll need to drag the file in), and add the following:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=JOSM Imports
GenericName=Java OpenStreetMap Editor
Comment=Editor for OpenStreetMap.org
Exec=JAVA_OPTS="-Djosm.home=/home/saikrishna/.josm-imports/" josm
Icon=josm.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Education;Geography;
```

This is what I have to run a custom instance of JOSM. Obviously, the content you'll have will be different.

Here is an explanation of each line:

- `Version=1.0`: Specifies the specification version of the `.desktop` file. Keep this unchanged.
- `Name=`: Name that will be displayed in the menu (if you put this in `~/.local/share/applications` or `/usr/share/applications`)
- `GenericName=`: Generic name of the program. This is like the category that a program falls under.
- `Comment=`: This may be used in displaying the tooltip.
- `Exec=`: This is what will be run when this file is activated. Unless what you are running is in your `$PATH`, I recommend you use an absolute path.
- `Icon=`: This is an icon file name that will be displayed. If there's no specific icon, you can skip this.
- `Terminal=`: Specify if a terminal window should open when this is activated. For GUI programs, this will typically be false.
- `Type=Application`: This is the type of `.desktop` file. There are other types, but leave this as-is.
- `Categories=`: This is the category that the program will fall under. This is mainly used in window managers that have hierarchical menus.

For a full list of valid keys and their descriptions, see [here](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s05.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So for the Exec section would I put my 'code' java -jar Example.jar 'code' before the path?

Comment: In your case, you should have `Exec=java -jar /path/to/Example.jar`.

Comment: Place it in `/usr/share/applications` to show it in the Applications menu.